# SQL Query Optimisation - taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Wondering if someone could help me optimise this query better as it's taking about 4 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT discount.*, retailer.name AS retailer_name, 
sub_category.type AS subcategory_type 
FROM discount 
  JOIN retailer ON retailer.id = discount.retailer 
  JOIN sub_category ON sub_category.id = discount.sub_category 
WHERE discount.start_date <= 1348133607 
AND retailer.closed = 0  
AND ( discount.only_for = 'PROC' OR discount.only_for = '' ) 
ORDER BY discount.updated_on DESC LIMIT 25
```

I have indexes on:

- discount.retailer
- discount.sub_category
- discount.start_date
- retailer.closed
- discount.only_for

Comment: Have you set-up foreign keys and indexes?

Comment: Why do you have indexes on start_date, closed and only_for ? Put index on the columns you usually join info ( id / retailer / sub_category )

Comment: Can you add the output of `EXPLAIN <YOUR QUERY>`?

Comment: Could you please show us: 1) execution plan 2) amount of rows per table.

Comment: Removed those 3 indexes which you said weren't needed. The output of EXPLAIN is:

`SIMPLE retailer ref PRIMARY,closed closed 1 const 1756 Using temporary; Using filesort`

`SIMPLE discount ref retailer,sub_category retailer 2 petobamarketing_xml.retailer.id 81 Using where`

`SIMPLE sub_category eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 petobamarketing_xml.discount.sub_category 1 Using where`

Answer (score 0):

You ought to have three indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX discount_ndx ON discount (only_for, start_date, retailer, sub_category);
CREATE INDEX retailer_ndx ON retailer (id, closed, name);
CREATE INDEX sub_category_ndx ON sub_category(id, type);
```

The first index allows immediate match on the `WHERE` based on `only_for` and `date` (you can try inverting those two keys in the index; it depends on data distribution. I would need the output of `EXPLAIN` to decide on that). The `retailer` value allows for completing the `JOIN` without having to retrieve the `discount` data at all.

From `retailer` table you only need `id` (straight join) and `closed` for the `WHERE`; and it might be worthwhile to store `name` in the index too. Finally, the `subcategory` table only provides `type`, so it makes sense having an index on that, *unless* `subcategory` is a very thin table containing little more than `id` and `type`.

Let me know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a problem. I had a query like `select * from ViewName v where v.column1 = 'ABCD'`

'ABCD' was a character. In explain plan, I saw that Oracle put FAST FULL SCAN INDEX on my script which is a poor index (its cost was 105).

Then, I wrote a function which was returning the same value, and replaced like `select * from ViewName v where v.column1 = FUNCTIONX`

Interestingly, I saw that Oracle used FULL SCAN INDEX (cost was 32) and my execution time improved remarkably.

I am not good at optimization, but I thought that maybe it helps